# Using a wild card character for the TEXTAFTER function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have the following values

`,t.RowCreated`

`,t.RowModified`

`,s.RowCreated`

`,s.RowModified`

`,q.RowCreated`

`,q.RowModified`

`,q.RowDeleted`

`(many more)`

As you can see, the character after the comma can be any one character.

This column contains other data, so using a simple after "." isn't feasible for this scenario.

I am trying to search for a pattern of ,*." to extract all text after.

I have tried to use the following formulas without success

`=TEXTAFTER(A1, ",?.")`

`=TEXTAFTER(A1, ",*.")`

`=TEXTAFTER(A1, ",~.")`

I get "#N/A" as a result for all cases.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Why not mid() starting at position 4 ?

Comment: If I am not wrong, `TEXTAFTER` function doesn't support wildcards. You can try this alternative. `=IFERROR(MID(A1, SEARCH(",?.", A1) + LEN(",?."), LEN(A1)), "")`

Comment: Try `=LET(d,A2:A11,p,",?.",n,"",IFERROR(RIGHT(d,LEN(d)-SEARCH(p,d)-LEN(p)+1),n))`.

Comment: @SolarMike this is not suitable as the column contains a variety of different text and lengths as it is an imported view from SQL.

Comment: @bs3ac so it's always a single character between the comma and dot? If so Siddharth's formula is perfect + you could apply it to the whole range at once.

Answer (score 3):

### Get Text After Characters Around a Wild Character

[image]

- This will only work with the `?` wild character because it counts it as a single character in `Len(p)`.

```
=LET(d,A2:A8,p,",?.",n,"",IFERROR(RIGHT(d,LEN(d)-SEARCH(p,d)-LEN(p)+1),n))
```

- To make it more flexible i.e. to additionally allow the `*` wild character, you could use the following that uses 3 'delimiters' (`fd, wd, sd`) the wild character (`wd`) being in the middle.

```
=LET(d,A2:A8,fd,",",wd,"*",sd,".",n,"",
    IFERROR(TEXTAFTER(RIGHT(d,LEN(d)-SEARCH(fd&wd&sd,d)-LEN(fd)),sd),n))
```

- The purpose of subtracting the length of the first delimiter (`-Len(fd)`) is to avoid the wrong result if the string represented by the wild character would start with the second delimiter (`sd`).

Answer (score 2):

You may have oversimplified your sample data, so I'm unsure this is applicable. `TEXTSPLIT()` does *not* support wildcard features. But you could just nest two of them:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTAFTER(TEXTAFTER(A1:A11,","),"."),"")
```

If you are looking to find a substring of a single character, you could use:

```
=TEXTAFTER(A1,","&MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)&".")
```

Comment: I'd expected a FilterXML version in here from you in this case ;)

Comment: @P.b, for you: `=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A11,",","</s><s>,")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,',')][substring(.,3,1)='.'][1]"),"")` =)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach could be like this using `TEXTAFTER()`:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=TEXTAFTER(A1:A11,","&CHAR(ROW(97:122))&".",,,,"")
```

---